# Create Nodejs JSON Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

I want to create a json Object in Nodejs. I am fairly new to Nodejs and Javascript. Below is the json format.

```
{
  "Req": {
  "addr": ["teleNumber:021544"],
  "sendAddre": "teleNumber:347889",
  "outSMSBinaryMessage": {"message": "asdfa12547"},
  "validityPeriod": "10"
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want to create a Javascript object from a Json string? :confused:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JSON is JavaScript object notation. What you have added is a JS object. If you want to create a JSON string, then use `JSON.stringify(yourObject)`. If we want to parse that JSON string, use `JSON.parse(yourObjectStringified)`.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking to create interfaces or classes? To get started, you can use online tools to convert JSON into Typescript interfaces.

https://jsonformatter.org/json-to-typescript

```
export interface Welcome10 {
Req: Req;
}

export interface Req {
    addr:                string[];
    sendAddre:           string;
    outSMSBinaryMessage: OutSMSBinaryMessage;
    validityPeriod:      string;
}

export interface OutSMSBinaryMessage {
    message: string;
}
```